# Использование Function.identity Причина: переменная вывода V#1 имеет несовместимые границы

Tags: java, функции, generics, cast

Пишу маппер полей эксельника в класс и при попытке обобщения столкнулся с проблемой конвертации `Double` в `Double,Long,Integer`.
Суть в том, что апачевская либа для получения числового значения из ячейки экселя имеет только метод `getNumericValue` - который возвращает `double`. Соответственно, мне нужно, зная класс, к которому я хочу преобразовать `double`, это преобразование сделать. Вот такой код

```
public class Main {

    class ConvertNumber {
        public static int toInt(Double a) {
            return a.intValue();
        }
        public static Double toDouble(Double a) {
            return a;
        }
    }
    private static final Map<Class<?>, DoubleFunction<?>> fFromDouble = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
            Integer.class, ConvertNumber::toInt,
            Double.class, Function.identity()
    ));
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> tClass = Integer.class;
        Double d = 10D;
        out.println(" new int " + myMethod(tClass, d));
    }

    public static <T> T myMethod(Class<T> tClass, Double d) {
        return tClass.cast(fFromDouble.get(tClass).apply(d));
    }
}
```

выдает ошибку

```
incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for HashMap<>
    private static final Map<Class<?>, DoubleFunction<?>> fFromDouble = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                                                                                   ^
    reason: inference variable V#1 has incompatible bounds
      equality constraints: DoubleFunction<?>
      lower bounds: V#2,Function<T,T>
  where V#1,V#2,K,T are type-variables:
    V#1 extends Object declared in class HashMap
    V#2 extends Object declared in method <K,V#2>of(K,V#2,K,V#2)
    K extends Object declared in method <K,V#2>of(K,V#2,K,V#2)
    T extends Object declared in method <T>identity()
```

Если вместо `Function.identity` использовать `ConvertNumber::toDouble` то все работает.
Если писать мапу вот так

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, Function<Double, ?>> 
fFromDouble = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
Double.class, Function.identity() ));
```

никакой ошибки нет, она появляется при попытке добавить другие классы. А вот такая мапа

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, DoubleFunction<?>> 
fFromDouble = new HashMap<>(Map.of( 
Double.class, Function.identity() ));
```

тоже выдает ошибку приведения типов.
Собственно, вопрос, а что там вообще происходит?
Буду рад, если поделитесь ссылками, что почитать по теме. И/или предложите свои варианты обобщенного приведения типов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DoubleFunction<R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleFunction.html) - это функция, принимающая строго аргумент примитивного `double` и возвращающая результат типа `R`.

[`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) -- это функция `Function<T, T>`, которая возвращает свой входной аргумент, соответственно, она не является `DoubleFunction<T>`.

Из-за несовпадения типов `DoubleFunction<R>` и `Function<T, T>` и происходит весь этот горький катаклизм, который мы наблюдаем.

У вас был вариант вместо `Function.identity` использовать лямбду: `x -> x`, которая *может* зарезолвиться компилятором как `DoubleFunction`:

```java
private static final Map<Class<?>, DoubleFunction<?>> fFromDouble = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
    Integer.class, ConvertNumber::toInt,
    Double.class, x -> x
));
```

---

Однако, если определить тип *значения* мапы как **`Function<Double, ?>`**, при попытке использовать следующий код с `Function.identity()` всё равно возникнет ошибка компиляции:

```java
private static final Map<Class<?>, Function<Double, ?>> mapFunction = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
    Integer.class, ConvertNumber::toInt,
    Double.class, Function.identity()
));

error: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for HashMap<>
private static final Map<Class<?>, Function<Double, ?>> mapFunction = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                                                                                 ^
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) K,V,T
      (argument mismatch; bad return type in method reference
        int cannot be converted to Double)
  where K,V,T are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in method <K,V>of(K,V,K,V)
    V extends Object declared in method <K,V>of(K,V,K,V)
    T extends Object declared in method <T>identity()
1 error
```

И проблема здесь вовсе не в использовании `int` в качестве типа результата функции `ConvertNumber.toInt`, аналогичная ошибка была бы и для типа-обёртки `Integer`: `Integer cannot be converted to Double`.

Загвоздка в том, что компилятор не может извлечь тип для вложенной неизменяемой мапы, которая возвращается методом `Map.of` с неявной типизацией, так как возникла следующая неоднозначность:
одно значение со ссылкой на метод имеет тип `Function<Double, int>`, а другое c `Function.identity()` подразумевает одинаковый тип аргумента и возвращаемого результата `Function<T, T>`.

Но если ему слегка помочь, указав *явно* типы ключа-значения во вложенной мапе, он справится:

```java
private static final Map<Class<?>, Function<Double, ?>> mapFunction = new HashMap<>(
    Map.<Class<?>, Function<Double, ?>>of(
        Integer.class, ConvertNumber::toInt,
        Double.class, Function.identity()
    )
);
```

Также вместо вложенной мапы можно использовать статический блок для инициализации, тогда указанная проблема вообще не возникнет:

```java
private static final Map<Class<?>, Function<Double, ?>> mapFunction2 = new HashMap<>();
static {
    mapFunction2.put(Integer.class, ConvertNumber::toInt);
    mapFunction2.put(Double.class, Function.identity());
}
```

Или же использовать инициализацию с двойными фигурными скобками (не рекомендуется как устаревший):

```java
private static final Map<Class<?>, Function<Double, ?>> mapFunction3 = new HashMap<>() {{
    put(Integer.class, ConvertNumber::toInt);
    put(Double.class, Function.identity());
}};
```

---

*Разумеется*, при замене `Function.identity()` на лямбду `x -> x` или ссылку на метод `ConvertNumber::toDouble`, данная проблема не возникнет *при использовании вложенной мапы*, как и в предыдущем случае:

```java
private static final Map<Class<?>, Function<Double, ?>> mapFunction4 = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
    Integer.class, ConvertNumber::toInt,
    Double.class, x -> x
));

private static final Map<Class<?>, Function<Double, ?>> mapFunction5 = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
    Integer.class, ConvertNumber::toInt,
    Double.class, ConvertNumber::toDouble
));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! но вот не дает покоя вопрос, а что со вторым вариантом мапы, через Function<Double, ?>> - с ней-то Function<T, T> работает, но перестает, если добавлять другие типы привидения.

Comment: @IgorEgorov, полезное замечание, дописал ответ для этого случая